# problema al imprimir pdf con conultas de mysql

Tags: php, html, pdf

hola tengo el siguiente problema

al mostrar el código marca y el código  separando por un etiqueta  td no me realizar   nada pero al mostrar los 2 campos separándolos  por algún simbolos me los muestra, es decir al colocar  2 etiqueta o natributo td en ese if solo me nuestra una sola variable

```
<tbody>
            <?php $j = 0; ?>
                <tr>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($equivalencias as $equivalencia) { 
                            if($j == 5){
                                $j = 0;
                                ?>
                                    </tr><tr>
                                <?php 
                            } 
                         if($equivalencia['id_marca'] == $mar['id']){
                    ?>

                            <td>
                                <?php echo $equivalencia['codigo_marca'] "</td> "; ?>
                         <td>
                                <?php echo $equivalencia['codigo']; ?>
                            </td>   
                             
                         
                               
                        <?php 
                            $j++; 
                        }
                        
                        
                    } 
                    if( $j != 0){
                        for($i = 0; $i < 5 - $j; $i++){
                            ?>
                              
                           <td></td>
                           <td></td>
                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

estoy imprimiendo en pdf

Comment: Hola Jhosy, sería bueno que agregaras en tu pregunta un ejemplo del valor la variable `$equivalencias`, o un ejemplo de que ves y como te gustaríaa que se vea. Utiliza la herramienta [edit].